# Instability When Multi-tasking on Machine for webdriver script

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am facing the following issue please Help me:

When using my computer at the same time the tests are running in
the background - it is very easy to make a test fail that would
otherwise have passed.  The easiest way to duplicate this is during
sendKeys - when text is appearing in a text box - if I click on the
browser title bar and hold and/or drag the window or try to work on eclipse at the same time - it is easy to
break a test.

I am using IE 7, Windows XP SP3.

Regards,
Gorav

Comment: Ideally you should not be interfering with tests that run on a browser. Dedicate a separate machine for your tests to run.

Comment: As long as you don't interfere with the actual browser, the tests should run just fine (assuming you are using Selenium 2).  However, Abhijeet is correct, there are a few cases where you can interfere with the tests, and you should use a separate machine to run your tests.

Comment: I want to run script and simultaneously work on eclipse. I am doing this to save time.In Selenium RC i can do, but why cant i do same with Webdriver? It expects focus on browser that means i need sit ideal. Unfortunately i got only one machine.

Regards,
Gorav
Is there any other way?